# Peer to peer network locking pattern (similiar to mutex/semaphore/monitor)

Tags: c#, locking

I want to do the following:

I have a number of computers. 
On each computer a programm will run.
There is no centralized server.

The program can choose by defined criteria to give another computer specified data. While doing so, the other computer should not do the same. (A sort of 2 way synchronize)

Let's make an example. (C1 .. Cn are the programs running on different computers)

C1 sends C2 updated data. While processing is active, C2 should not ask C1 for update something else.

The idea was:

1. C1 sends a message to C2: PauseExecution()
2. C1 sends to C2 items to be processed (updates some data on C2)
3. C1 sends a message to C2: ResumeExecution().
4. C2 sends a message to C1: PauseExecution()
5. C2 sends to C1 items to be processed (updates some data on C1)
6. C2 sends a message to C1: ResumeExecution().

But now the biggest problem arises.

If C1 sends a message to C2 to Pause, and C22 sends at the same tiem a message to C1 to Pause, both would block.

There is no centralized server / shared memory for keeping a semaphore.

Is there another pattern which can be used, so that n computers will not block?

So this question is about algorithmic exclusion.

Or is there another workaround for this problem?

Comment: You'll likely find a better audience for this on Programmers.StackExchange.com. This kind of high-level algorithm design isn't suited to practical problems StackOverflow caters for.

Comment: @tragedian thanks, Programmes.StackExchange helped.

Answer (score 1):

Why not sending reply messages to the requests and and re run requests in different time intervals;

C1 sends a message to C2: PauseExecution() (reply: Not OK)

C2 sends a message to C1: PauseExecution() (reply: Not OK)

C1 receives reply message (waits for a random time before sending another message)

C2 receives reply message (waits for a random time before sending another message)

C1 sends a message to C2: PauseExecution() (reply: OK)

Comment: I think the problem in this case is the (reply Not OK). If both execute the method on different machines at the same time, I think it would be possible that both give a Not OK instead of an OK. Maybe it could be made if a token would be passed between them, an only the owner of the token is allowed to Pause. but then the question would be: what happens if the one with the token is removed from network and so on. I would also accept suggestions which point in some busy wait direction.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to give both not ok. but in this case, they will try to resend after a different time interval (which may be base on the id of the clients).

Comment: sorry, i meant: beccause of timeing 2 times OK could occur, if both check the same thing independly without an lock on an object

Comment: 2 OK messages are not possible; there are two states for each client: sending or not sending. If sending, then it is not possible to send an OK message; if not sending, then it will send an OK message and will not try to send data to other clients. Sorry if I miss some points...

Comment: Oh i mean the following case: Both are not sending at the moment. Both try to send, and therefore ask the other one for pause. As both have not reached the state sending, both could go to pause and send OK (and therefore wait forever). But if i think about it, maybe you meant that a sender directly goes to sending and then asks for pause? Maybe if alock is used to mutually exclude PuaseExecution and StartSending (also that could trigger a connection timeout for larger sends).

Comment: maybe before sending (prepairing to send) the message you may set the state as "sending"; thus client may send NOT OK even it is not sending but it will start to send.

Comment: Thanks, something only a bit more complex is done right now with the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricart%E2%80%93Agrawala_algorithm (The english wiki is not very good for it, but you also use a priority to choose which one can send, we just enhanced it with a method to repriortize if both have same prio)